# How to get Database folders

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Hello everyone thank you for your help.

I want to create schemas and have tables under schemas. I am able to do that.

However when browsing them, none of the tables come under the schema listed. The folder structure under database folder is tables, views, etc as hierarchy and under tables there are table names as schema_name.table_name eg as attached, which is all cluttered.

I’ve checked under security to see the list of all schemas created, but can’t expand them there to find tables under it either.

P.S. There are other schemas other than the default `dbo` which are just under the same list.

How do I organise so that there are schemas and the folders under schemas are tables, views, etc. for that schema and so on. I am using Microsoft sql server management tool and VS code

> [image]

Comment: This is just a display thing of SSMS, rather than a feature of the database engine. Other applications show it differently, for example DataGrip.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to change the hierarchical order of how SQL Server Management Studio displays its nodes in the Object Explorer. This is how SSMS was designed to display objects, which a schema itself is a database object not a folder.

You may find it helpful to right click on the parent folder (e.g. the "Tables" folder) of the objects you're working with, then click on Filter, and you can filter by a particular schema at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can we create a new DB and have initial hierarchy as schemas and then next level to be tables, views, etc folders?

Comment: @SSR No, unfortunately there's no way to change the hierarchy, as my answer discusses.